# NHibernate Purge/Truncate Table and repopulate in single transaction

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Have a table with no relationships and an integer primary key.  Using NHibernate I want to repopulate the table in a single transaction like so:

- openTrans
- delete all rows
- insert new rows (many will have same ID as those deleted previously)
- commitTrans

However NHibernate throws 'a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session' at the point where I try to Save the new entity.  This makes sense as I have in fact created a new entity with the same Id.  I have tried to hoodwink NHibernate by overriding GetHashCode and Equals on the entity class so that two objects with same ID are 'equal' but I get the same result.

Another approach I could take is to update entities that already exist, remove existing entities not in the new data set and add new entities, but this is a lot of work I was hoping to avoid as the story is simply to repopulate the table. I could of course do this over two sessions but I want the whole operation to be atomic.

Comment: Could you just not use NHibernate here?

Comment: I am using NHibernate.  I have now implemented the second option which gives me the exact behavior I need albeit with a little more effort.

Comment: Delete the rows using createsql and truncate. Then insert. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
session.Clear();  // to get rid associations of the objects in memory
session.CreateQuery("delete from MyClass").ExecuteUpdate();
foreach(var entity in CreateNew())
    session.Save(entity);
```

**Option 2**

```
session.CreateQuery("delete from MyClass where Id not in (:ids)")
    .SetParameterList("ids", newIds)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
foreach (var id in newIds)
{
    var entity = session.Get<MyClass>(id); // returns the cached instance if present or the database instance or null if non existant
    if (entity == null)
    {
        entity = new MyClass { Id = id };
        session.Save(entity);
    }
    Populate(entity);
}
```

**Option 3**

```
var newEntities = CreateNew();

session.CreateQuery("delete from MyClass where Id not in (:ids)")
    .SetParameterList("ids", newEntities.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray())
    .ExecuteUpdate();

foreach(var entity in newEntities)
    session.Merge(entity);  // will get the object with the same id and copies over properties over
```

Comment: Is the query string literal or does NHibernate translate it for the target DB platform? I'm assuming the format of the string may be different for different platforms. I would like to keep the code platform agnostic if at all possible.

Comment: the literal is HQL which is object query language and platform independent. i think 'delete MyClass where Id not in (:ids)' should work too